# What is the range of $g(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{5-x}}{y^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

> How to find range of $2$ variable function $\displaystyle g(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{5-x}}{y^2}$ for real $x,y$

My way

First i calculate domain  of that function

Here $5-x\geq 0\;\cap\; y\neq 0\Longrightarrow x\leq 5\;\cap\;  y\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

And for calculation of range

Largest value of $g(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$ when $y\rightarrow \pm \infty$ but how i find lowest value of range

But i did not understand how to find range of function

Please help me to find range of function

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ real numbers? What is the domain of $g$? Is it the largest subset of the real numbers for which $g(x,y)$ is again a real number? Are you familiar with complex numbers? Also, there are a few speling mistakes and mathematical errors; presumably you mean $\wedge$ instead of $\cap$.

Comment: Largest value of $g(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$ when $y\rightarrow \pm \infty$ but how i find lowest value of $g(x,y)$

Comment: If $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then the numerator is non-negative and the denominator is positive; the lowest value of $g(x,y)$ occurs when $x=5$; also, when $y\to\pm\infty,$ $g(x,y)\to0$

Comment: You mean $\sqrt{5-x}\geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{y^2}>0$. So can we say range of $g(x,y)\in[0,\infty)$

Comment: Can the numerator be negative?  Can the denominator?  Can the numerator be zero?  What is the smallest value in the range?

Comment: @jacky:  That's what I mean, so the range of $g(x,y)$ is contained in $[0,\infty)$; can you find $x$ and $y$ such that $g(x,y)=a$ for any $a\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Lowest value is exactly $0$ when $x=5$

Comment: Thanks so much Got it.

Comment: @jacky:  you could post an answer for further feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g$ has real inputs and outputs only. Then consider the domain: $x \leq 5$ and $y \neq 0$. The numerator can be as small as $0$ and as large as you'd like ($x=-105$ yeilds a numerator of 10). The denominator can be "very close" to $0$ and as large as you like. Notice that you cannot get negative results.  So, the smallest the output can be is $0$ ($x=5, y\neq 0$). How big can the output get? As long as $x$ is not 5, we can make the number very big, for simplicity let $x=4$, so that the numerator takes value 1. Now, $1/y^2$ can be made as large as you like. Say you want to make it size M, choose $y = 1/\sqrt{M}$. In other words, for all $x <5$, $$\lim_{y\to 0}g(x,y) =\infty $$ So $g \in [0,\infty)$.